# AudioCache player wont play with delays

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use AudioCache to play sequence of audio assets when app starts. I want to play the audio in eigth beat (188ms delays). The audio assets themselves work properly and so does the AudioCache player but when i try to play the note they all play very fast.
I have used following methods and none worked for me:

```
    //188ms because beat is eigth note
    player.play('note1.wav');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ));
    player.play('note1.wav');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ));
    player.play('note5.wav');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ));
    player.play('note4.wav');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ));
    player.play('note4.wav');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ));
    player.play('note3.wav');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ));
    player.play('note4.wav');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ));
    player.play('note5.wav');
```

also this:

```
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note1'));
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note1'));
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note5'));
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note4'));
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note4'));
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note3'));
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note4'));
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 188 ), () => player.play('note5'));
```

I wrote it in a function which is called inside build(context). Is there another function for delays that i need to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaining them together, like this:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 188), () {
   player.play('note1.wav');
   Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 188), () {
        player.play('note5.wav');
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 188), () {
            player.play('note4.wav');
      }); // etc...
   });
});
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot, so the delay works between the callback argument lines?